# Getting environment variables with SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to get system/environment variables with SQLite?
I know that by using sqlite3's command line I can do something like:

```
sqlite> .shell echo $USER
```

But I want to know if I can implement this in a SQL trigger.

We have multiple users using a shared sqlite database and I want to create an automatic log that records who made that changes to specific tables.

Comment: As a serverless database by design, it will be hard to get a notion of a user out of SQLite when defining a trigger schema.  SQLite is designed to be used on systems that may not even have a shell to call.  If you need a concept of users, you should probably be using a database server like PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not know anything about environment variables. (Many systems on which it runs do not even have them.)

The easiest way to get a user name into a trigger would be to [create a user-defined function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), but then the trigger would fail if used outside a program that has registered this function.